# Apply Embedded CSS to Content Page

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

I have a master page and a content page for my ASP.NET web forms site. Both pages have style blocks.

The following is from my content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">        
    <style type="text/css" runat="server">
        .scroll td:nth-of-type(1)::before {
            content: "Column Name";
            color: black;
        } ...
```

And the master page:

```
<head id="Head1">
    <style type="text/css" runat="server">
    ...
    </style>
    ...    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" /> ...
```

The rendered HTML only applies the content style block under two conditions: page refresh and disabling jQuery Mobile. Everything else seems to make no difference, and I have been unsuccessful at getting the style block to apply changes on the initial page load on the content page without disabling jQuery Mobile.

The style block is present at all times, but is not normally applied. I have tried to move the style to the body. I have deleted the master page's style block. I have experimented with `runat="server"`. Also, the order of the content placeholder in relation to the master page's style block doesn't matter. Style from the *master* page is always rendered. I have compared the rendered source code before and after a page refresh and the rendered HTML pages pre and post refresh are identical despite the fact that only the refreshed page works as anticipated.

Is there something that I'm missing? I am using ASP.NET v4.5 *Web Forms* and Visual Studio 2012 update 4?

Comment: This should work fine - might be a typo in the content page markup

Comment: @Daniel you were on to something. The problem has something to do with jQuery Mobile apparently. If I disable jQuery mobile but not jQuery then I get proper rendering of CSS styles. This should teach me not to use jQuery with Web Forms.